# jquery ui autocomplete not working in ie8 (until page refresh)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery ui autocomplete it is working absolutely fine in all browsers except ie8.

I have been doing some testing and there seems to be a strange bug. When I click on a link leading to the relevant page there is the following error generated by ie8 when I start typing in the autocomplete box:

'object doesn't support this property or method'
this error points to my development jquery(1.4.2) file at line 4955, char 5 which is the following line:
return new window.XMLHttpRequest();

However, if I simply reload the page the autocomplete works.

I have added a random bit of data to be called with the autocomplete as I read that ie8 caches it ajax get requests but this does not seem to have solved the problem.

Could there be a problem with the timing of the loading of all the relevant files including jquery? If so, how would I fix this?
Any other clever ideas?!

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of trial and error I found the answer to be very simple!

I was calling the meta tag...

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

...after the javascript include files. All other browsers except IE8 allowed this.

That'll be a lesson I won't forget soon - many hours spent fixing!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are trying to use the asynchronous Ajax-call synchronously.

You should use a callback-function in which you retreive the data.

= or =

You should configure the call to be synchronous:

```
jQuery.ajax( {async: false} );
```