# jQuery autocomplete 'length' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 3 application and I'm trying to properly incorporate the [jQuery autocompletex](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) into one of my pages so a user can type in an ingredient name or choose one from the dropdown.

I get this error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'length' is null or not an object
```

and my view code looks like this:

```
$("#ingredientid").autocomplete({
   source: function (request, response) {
      $.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("AvailableIngredients", "Recipe")', type: "POST", dataType: "json",
         data: { query: request.term },
         success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
               return { label: item, value: item };
            }))
         }
      })
   },
   minLength: 1
});
```

Things seem to work fine in Firefox, but IE 8 is the standard browser used in-house.

---

**Additional:**

I'm returning the data - `List<string>` like so:

```
public JsonResult AvailableIngredients()
{
   ... 
   return Json(allIngredients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Ideas?

Comment: Everything looks good to me, have you validated your json response in jsonlint.com? What content type are you returning the json as? Could something else be throwing this error?

Comment: @KevinB - Unfortunately I can't put the box on the internet to do that - company IP on it.  I'm pretty sure that it's this because I don't get that error when I'm not using autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to declare your meta tag for content type before your javascript include files. looks like that was a problem for someone else in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823018/jquery-ui-autocomplete-not-working-in-ie8-until-page-refresh) question.

Comment: did you try and make the ajax call syncronous?