# Jquery autocomplete not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

```
function getclassno(cat){   
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url:"reg/data/data.php", 
        data:{
            catogery:cat  
        },
        success: function(data){     
            $.each(data, function (i, elem) {        
                $('#classno').append( new Option(elem.id) );            
            });              
        }
    );

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUBJECTCODE  FROM subjectmaster WHERE CATCODE = '$cat'");  
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $return_arr = array(); 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $row_array['id']=$row[0];     
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);    
    }

    echo json_encode($return_arr);         
}
```

I used above code to populate autocomplete with data.it works in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE8

Comment: what is the error you got? and where you use autocomplete?

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823018/jquery-ui-autocomplete-not-working-in-ie8-until-page-refresh.

Comment: What is the json coming back? Is there an IE error?

Comment: i wont get any error.i checkd your link.why should i do the async: false,.

Comment: Did you read the post? are you using any meta tags in your page?